# Django queryset over multiple foreign keys using prefetch_related

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-queryset

Here are my models:

```
class Owner():
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...

class Species():
    species_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    ...

class Pet():
    client = models.ForeignKey(Owner, related_name='pet_fk')
    species = models.ForeignKey(Species)
    ....
```

I want to list all owners and their pets. Some owners have no pets, others have many.

If a pet is found I want to annotate an extra 'temporary' field `css_species_class` to that animal's object. This field will return 'dog' if the species_code for the pet model is 'CANINE', or 'horse' if 'EQUINE' etc.

The 'temporary' field is needed due to the site being multilingual and the `css_species_class` value is needed to pull in appropriate glyph icons in the template. I can't use the value stored directly, so that's why I need to insert a specific value to match the value expected by the glyphs.

Something like:

```
Owner: John Smith
Pet: Saag (css_species_class='dog')
Pet: Brinjal (css_species_class='cat')
Pet: Baji (css_species_class='dog')

Owner: Sue Smith
Pet: none

Owner: Clare Smith
Pet: Aloo (css_species_class='horse')
```

My template is something like this:

```
{% for owner in owners %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ owner.first_name }} {{ owner.last_name }}</td>
        <td> <!-- loop over pet objects -->
            {% for pet in owner.pet_fk.all %}
                <div>
                    ....
                    <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-{{ pet.css_species_class }}"></span>
                    ....
                </div>
            {% endfor pet %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

So, here's my first stab at a solution:

```
class OwnerListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'visitors/owner_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'owners'
    paginate_by = 50

    def get_queryset(self):
        owners_with_pets = Owner.objects.filter(pet_fk__isnull=False).prefetch_related('pet_fk').distinct()
            # logic goes here to loop over pets
            # and assign 'css_species_class' temp field

        owners_without_pets = Owner.objects.filter(pet_fk__isnull=True).prefetch_related('pet_fk').distinct()
```

Then 'merge' the two querysets together:

```
        result_list = sorted(
            chain(owners_with_pets, owners_without_pets),
            key=attrgetter('last_name'))
            return result_list
```

This 'works' for a small number of owners but if I test with the real number (about 4,000) I get 'too many sql variable' errors.

I originally tried doing this in a single query (before deciding to break it up into two queries) but that failed spectacularly as well for larger numbers of clients.

Could someone kindly give me a bit of guidance as to how best approach this? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, not tested but I presume it works.

```
class Owner():
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...

class Species():
    species_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    ...

class Pet():
    # related_name is used for backward relation
    # this will end up as owner."related_name" --> owner.pets
    client = models.ForeignKey(Owner, related_name='pets')
    species = models.ForeignKey(Species)
    ...

    @property
    def css_species_class(self):
        # this could be anything you want eg: css_scecies_class
        return self.species.species_code


class OwnerListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'visitors/owner_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'owners'
    paginate_by = 50

    def get_queryset(self):
        # no need to check if onwner instance has pets if you chain them both back
        return Owner.objects.prefetch_related('pets').all().distinct()

{% for owner in owners %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ owner.first_name }} {{ owner.last_name }}</td>
        <td> <!-- loop over pet objects -->
            {% for pet in owner.pets %}
                <div>
                    ....
                    <!-- now we can access pet.css_species_class directly because we made it a property of pet class -->
                    <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-{{ pet.css_species_class }}"></span>
                    ....
                </div>
            {% endfor pet %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```